# How many spaces for tab character(\t)?

Tags: c++, c, printf

I want to implement a text drawing function. But I am not sure how `\t` works, which means I don't know how many spaces I should print for `\t`.

I have come up with the following algorithm:

a) Each `\t` represents at most `NUMBER_OF_SPACES_FOR_TAB` spaces.
b) If `\t` appears in the last line at a corresponding position, `\t` for this line should be aligned to the `\t` of last line.

Example:

```
printf("a\t\tb\n");
printf("\t\tc\n");
```

Should print:

```
a11112222b
34444c
```

Where:

1.Number `i` represents the spaces of `\t` at position `i`

2.`NUMBER_OF_SPACES_FOR_TAB == 4`

Does anyone know the standard algorithm? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Text editors usually align tabs on every Xth column, independently of other characters

Comment: Do you guess or do you know? The rules you describe are not the usual ones for tabs, although maybe you have been told to use them.

Comment: @john I just guess whether there is a standard algorithm

Comment: Well the usual rule is what alestanis said.

Comment: And, please, treat a tab as a character of its own. Never think of it as a shorthand for a bunch of spaces. I cannot count the number of source files that I've seen where some brain-dead editor totally ruined the indentation because it was programmed to treat a tab as a fixed amount of spaces. It's a separate character, a character that carries some very important meaning of its own, and a character that should be treated with respect.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica It is its own character yes. But what you're saying is not correct in every case nor is it desired in every case. Or did you forget about `expand(1)`? Sometimes spaces are desired over tabs.

Comment: @Pryftan `expand` is a tool that allows formatting tab separated database files into sensible table grids, giving single character entries less space than a name field, for instance. This is a pure one-way conversion, as it looses the semantic meaning of the tabs: Two tabs in sequence may be formatted to eight spaces, yet they signified an empty entry in between. The braindead part is the `unexpand` tool that pretends that this loss of information did not happen. If you `expand` a file for pretty printing, fine. Your choice. But, please, do not pretend it's equivalent to the original.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A tab character should advance to the next *tab stop*. Historically tab stops were every 8th character, although smaller values are in common use today and most editors can be configured.

I would expect your output to look like the following:

```
123456789
a       b
        c
```

The algorithm is to start a column count at zero, then increment it for each character output. When you get to a tab, output `n-(c%n)` spaces where `c` is the column number (zero based) and `n` is the tab spacing.

Comment: What about the algorithm I mentiond?

Comment: Often are 4 spaces used today. For languages with many levels also 2 are not uncommon.

Comment: @rekire and Mr Torvalds still advises using 8, and he has a pretty good reason :)

Comment: @Grizzly do you know what his reasoning is?

Comment: @Mark Ransom as you describes, the tab after character 'a' would just be 7 spaces(which I think it would be better if it is 8)?

Comment: @ComboZhc, no 7 spaces is the correct answer. The 'a' takes one space so it only takes 7 to get to stop.

Comment: @H2CO3: Reason of Mr. Torvalds is disputable if you read any of the stuff he regularly posts on the internet... regardless, _anyone_ recommending spaces for tabs doesn't have much understanding of what tabs are. Tabs are not spaces. One tab indents by _one level_, that's not 1 space, nor 2, nor 4, nor 8, nor any other number. Common excuses range from "but it looks like this" via "we've always done that" to "some people I have to work with use editors that can't do tabs", but none of the excuses is truly valid.

Comment: Or, worded differently, claiming that a tab is 8 spaces is like claiming that å is the same as a, or a dash, a hyphen, and a minus sign are the same thing, И is the russian N, and Я is the russian R.

Comment: @Damon: Oh thank god. Someone sane. Most people I run into nowadays swear blind that tab indentation is evil. They can never provide a good explanation as to why. It's starting to drive me insane!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Full Ack. And the code editors of those people are even worse. I've seen code indented with three spaces, but whenever more than eight spaces accumulated, they were replaced by a tab. It almost hurts physically to look at the resulting mess with a tab setting of four, the third level would appear further to the left than the second level! Completely unreadable until you've reindented the whole thing.

Comment: @cmaster that's why I prefer to use editors that replace tabs with spaces.  Tabs can be ambiguous, spaces never are.

Comment: @MarkRansom Tabs are not ambiguous. They carry meaning. One tab = one indentation level. How wide I want to *display* that indentation level, is my choice. I don't want to be forced by highly influential code developers to view my code with an indentation width of 8. If that code is properly formatted with tabs, I can view it with an indentation of, say, three, while Mr. Torvalds can view the same code with eight. My editor, my choice how it's displayed. The problems start when someone, or some tool, thinks they can replace a tab with eight spaces. That's just not the meaning of a tab.

Comment: @cmaster you're demonstrating the problem right there. If two people with different tab configurations view the same file, they'll get different representations. There are bound to be places that don't look right because things don't line up anymore.

Comment: @MarkRansom No, there are not. If the tabs are used for their designed purpose only, there are no such places: Indentation stays indentation, and alignment needs to be done with spaces, not tabs. Really, I'm using tab indentation everywhere where I have the choice, and the code that I produce can be viewed correctly with *any* tab setting. The only key to achieving this is to use tabs for indentation only, and spaces for alignment only. The two characters carry different meaning, and they need to be used as such.

Comment: @cmaster once you get used to using tabs, it's very difficult to switch between tabs and spaces as necessary.  You *will* start using tabs for alignment.  My recommendation to use an editor that converts tabs to spaces is based on my own experience, not theory - it's the way our entire team works, and it works very well for us.  But we've also standardized our indentation levels, which helps a lot too.

Comment: @MarkRansom Well, I'm programming for 25 years now, always indenting with tabs. And no, I never use tabs for alignment. Some editors do such brain-dead things, which were written by people who never meditated a second on the difference between a tab and a space. But even those editors can be taught not to do such nasty stuff. I mean, it's not that complicated. We are programming much, much more complex stuff in much, much more complex languages. You cannot tell me that we are not able to use tabs and spaces correctly...

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Maybe, maybe .. but what is correct when it comes to style? It's subjective. Your opinion is just that: your opinion. Just like other styles are a different opinion. None are correct or incorrect. They just are. It doesn't make it brain dead. It makes it a stylistic choice.

Comment: @Pryftan Yet, there are styles that are technically inferior/superior in certain aspects. The style that distinguishes between indentation (tabs) and alignment (spaces) is unquestionably superior in that it is flexible to the viewing style of the viewer. It does not chain the viewer to the preferred indentation width of the author. I don't care what indentation width you prefer as long as I can see your code with my preferred indentation width. And I want you to be able to see my code with your preferred indentation width as well. So, please, use tabs and spaces for what they are meant for.

Answer (score 28):

Imagine a ruler with tab stops every 8 spaces. A tab character will align text to the next tab stop.

```
                                0       8       16      24      32      40
                                |.......|.......|.......|.......|.......|
printf("\tbar\n");              \t      bar
printf("foo\tbar\n");           foo\t   bar
printf("longerfoo\tbar");       longerfoo\t     bar
```

To calculate where the next tab stop is, take the current `column`.

```
nextTabStop = (column + 8) / 8 * 8
```

The `/ 8 * 8` part effectively truncates the result to the nearest multiple of 8. For example, if you're at column 11, then (11 + 8) is 19 and 19 / 8 is 2, and 2 * 8 is 16. So the next tab stop from column 11 is at column 16.

In a text editor you may configure tab stops to smaller intervals, like every 4 spaces. If you're simulating what tabs look like at a terminal you should stick with 8 spaces per tab.

Comment: The tab after `foo` represents 5 spaces? I would assume it would be better if is 8 spaces.

Comment: Is 'column' understood by standard library? The math of tabs and spaces is clear, but is it not based on reference of 'columns'?

Comment: `column` is a hypothetical variable that you need to keep track of yourself. The standard library does not know the current column position of the cursor, no.

Answer (score 8):

A Tab character shifts over to the next tab stop. By default, there is one every 8 spaces. But in most shells you can easily edit it to be whatever number of spaces you want (profile preferences in linux, set tabstop in vim).

Answer (score 0):

By default, an output terminal consists of 25 rows and 80 columns. A set of 8 columns is called a frame, so your output terminal has a total of 10 frames on each row.

Whenever the compiler see `'\t'`, it moves the courser to the next available frame. So `'\t'` can sometimes seem to give 3 spaces, other times 1, it all depends on how far the next frame is.

- Example 1:

  ```c
  printf("Hell\to")
  ```

  Will output:

  ```bash
  "Hell    o"
  ```

  There's a total of 4 spaces, as the next frame is 4 spaces apart.
- Example 2:

  ```c
  printf("happily\tmarried")
  ```

  Will output:

  ```
  "happily        married"
  ```

  There's a total of 8 spaces, as the next frame is 8 spaces apart.