# Replace \t (tab) in string with number of spaces tab contains in Java

Tags: java, xml, string, xml-parsing

I have XML tag which contains string such as

```
<Narrative>I am String       with tab</Narrative>
```

When we read this XML and  store it in Java variable, it gets transformed to as follows

```
String narrativeText = "I am String \t with tab";
```

We want to replace \t with the number of spaces that tab character contains as our end system throws an exception if \t is received in string.

How many spaces does java consider as tab?

P.S. I don't want to use `replace` or `replaceAll` methods  of String class to remove \t by blank character  because I want to contain
number of spaces that \t char contains.

Sonar plugin is giving warning : Remove the non-escaped \u0009 character from this literal.

Comment: How to replace that tab with number of spaces?

Answer (score 2):

Java does not have any special meaning to tab.

Traditionally printers moved to the next column that was a multiple of eight (8,16,24 etc).

I would suggest building a new string from your old string character by character, where tabs are treated by adding spaces to the length of the new string is a multiple of eight.

Comment: Sonar plugin is giving warning : Whitespace and control characters in literals should be explicit

Comment: Does the sonar manual have an explanation for this warning?

Comment: Tabs of 8 stem from the era of type writers of 80 characters, 8 inch, copied to ADM3A terminals. Fixed sized screen font.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some confusion. Tab isn't actually what you are thinking. `\t` is not equivalent to spaces (although it is considered sometimes). Tab actually means the next stoppage of the tab. The stoppage of `tab` is mostly after the interval of multiples of `4` or `8`.

Watch this for a better reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13094734/15862198

Answer (score 1):

If you want a tab of 4 spaces:

```
"\ty"    -> "    y"  4 spaces
"x\ty"   -> "x   y"  3 spaces
"xx\ty"  -> "xx  y"  2 spaces
"xxx\ty" -> "xxx y"  1 space
```

So you need a bit of programming, which can best be done in java instead of XML. (You could also make a java function called in XML in case of XSLT.)

As tabs are typically for simple monospaced script, the code simplifies, uses `length()` in chars, and does not consider combining diacritical marks and other zero or double length code points.

```
public static String untab(String s, int tabSize) {
    if (tabSize <= 0) {
        return s.replace("\t", "");
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    s.codePoints().forEach(cp -> {
        if (cp == '\t') {
            do {
                sb.append(' ');
            } while ((sb.length() % tabSize) != 0);
        } else {
            sb.appendCodePoint(cp);
        }
        // Or: sb.append(" ".repeat(tabSize - (sb.length() % tabSize)));
    });
    return sb.toString();
}
```

A fully correct version would best work with **font** rendering i.o. `length()`.

Comment: exactly what to pass in tabSize?

Comment: so this method is as good as narrativeText  =  narrativeText .replaceAll("\t", " "); if we consider tabsize = 1

Comment: Nobody uses tabsize 1

Comment: @PawanPatil tabSize 1 would indeed replace the tab with a single space. That would also be an approach, for instance if the text is used in normal HTML.