# Formatting Issue with for loop c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a game called 'NIM' (See code introduction if you aren't familiar). When I output the 'blocks' they aren't spaced out evenly. I may be missing the obvious, but can someone point out where I'm going wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace NIM
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Introduction();
            InitialBoardSetUp();
        }
        static void Introduction()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\tWelcome to NIM!\n");
            Console.WriteLine("   - Each player takes their turn to remove a certain number of 'blocks' from a stack, of which there are 7.");
            Console.WriteLine("   - This happens until there is only 1 'block' remaining. With the winner being the one to remove the last 'block'.\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Initialising the board:\n");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
        static void InitialBoardSetUp()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("     " + i + "\t");
            }
            
            Console.Write("\n\n");

            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(" "+ i);

                for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("  ███\t");
                }
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what should be the output?

Comment: don't `Thread.Sleep(2000);` to simulate some long processing, users never like to wait haha

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of how they look now?

Comment: @Peter I made a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aptvwH)

Comment: 1-7 along the top and 1-7 down the side (Which it does). Then underneath each number on the top, a stack of "█" characters (3x7) (Which it does), evenly spaced out. But only stacks 2-7 are evenly spaced and the first isnt.

Comment: Is it just that the characters are different widths at the left side?

Comment: Yes, Kinda. The first stack is to the side a bit

Comment: @Nobody the header (numbers 1 - 7 at top) have 5 white spaces + the number + a tabulation (6 characters + tab), while the board has 2 white spaces + 3 block characters + tabulation (5 characters + tab). just add a space in the board or remove one in the header

Comment: `Console.Write("  ███ \t");` does the job (notice the space before the `\t`)

Comment: May I recommend this: [Tutorial: Debug a .NET console application using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/debugging-with-visual-studio?pivots=dotnet-6-0) (13 minutes to read)

Comment: When writing lines you start with 2 characters (`Console.Write(" "+ i);` and then 4 characters + a tab for every column.   In the header your start with 0 characters, and then  6 characters + a tab (`Console.Write("     " + i + "\t");`).  the lines are 2+4*7=30 characters, the head is 0+6*7=42 characters (when not counting the `\t`)

Comment: BTW: I did not count the tab characters because I would not use them here. To know what they do you could read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13094734/724039

Comment: When running your program from a cmd window you can redirect the output to a text file (`nim.exe > C:\Temp\nim.txt`). Then you can open the text file in Notepad which will allow you to use the arrow keys to figure out the spacing.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is your code with some minor modifications. `\t` has been removed and replaced with spaces. Spaces added before writing the column headers. Added comments.

Try the following:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace NIM
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Introduction();
            InitialBoardSetUp();
        }

        static void Introduction()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\tWelcome to NIM!\n");
            Console.WriteLine("   - Each player takes their turn to remove a certain number of 'blocks' from a stack, of which there are 7.");
            Console.WriteLine("   - This happens until there is only 1 'block' remaining. With the winner being the one to remove the last 'block'.\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Initialising the board:\n");
            //Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }

        static void InitialBoardSetUp()
        {
            //add space for row numbers
            Console.Write("  ");

            //print column headers
            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("   " + i + "   ");
            }

            Console.Write("\n\n");

            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
            {
                //print row numbers
                Console.Write(" " + i);

                for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
                {
                    //print blocks
                    Console.Write("  ███  ");
                }

                Console.Write("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```