# Python Output not Aligned Using Space and Tab

Tags: python

My code is here:

```
days = int(input("How many days did you work? : "))
totalSalary = 0
print("Day", "\tDaily Salary", "\tTotal Salary")
for day in range(days):
    daily = 2**day
    totalSalary += daily
    print(day+1, "\t    ", daily, "\t\t    ", totalSalary)
```

When I enter 6 as input, here is the output:

```
Day     Daily Salary    Total Salary
1            1               1
2            2               3
3            4               7
4            8               15
5            16                      31
6            32                      63
```

Why last 2 lines are not aligned?

Edit: I forgot to say that I know there are better solutions like using format, but I just wanted to understand why there is problem with tabs and spaces.

Edit2: The visualization of tabstops in Jason Yang's answer satisfied me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For statement

```py
    print(day+1, "\t    ", daily, "\t\t    ", totalSalary)
```

each `'\t'` will stop at 1, 9, 17, ..., at each 8th character

So it will look like this

```py
1=------____=1=-........____=1
2=------____=2=-........____=3
3=------____=4=-........____=7
4=------____=8=-........____=15
5=------____=16=--------........=31
6=------____=32=--------........=63
12345678123456781234567812345678 <--- Tab stop before each 1
```

Here

- `=` is the separator space between each two arguments of print
- `-` is the space generated by not-last TAB
- `_` is the space specified by you in your print.
- `.` is the sapce generated by last TAB.

From here you can find the differece why they stop at different position.

Try to add option `sep=''` in your print, or change the numbers of spaces you added.

```py
    print(day+1, "\t    ", daily, "\t\t    ", totalSalary, sep='')
```

then it will be fine.

```py
How many days did you work? : 6
Day     Daily Salary    Total Salary
1           1               1
2           2               3
3           4               7
4           8               15
5           16              31
6           32              63
```

Comment: This helped a lot. So in the first four lines, tab in the middle printed just 1 space. But in the last two lines, because of additional digit, that 1 space disappeared. So tab in the middle printed the whole 8 spaces! Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are right !

Answer (score 0):

When the 2nd columns has double digit values, the rest of the tab and 3rd column gets shifted. You must use zero padding for the values, if you expect correctly aligned column values.

If your python version is 3+, and if you want 2 digit values, you can call `print(f'{n:02}')`, so as to print `01` if the value of n was having 1.

For 2.7+ version of python, you could use the `format` like so `print('{:02d}'.format(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your question is due to a misunderstanding on what a tab character is and how it behaves:

> A tab character should advance to the next tab stop. Historically tab stops were every 8th character, although smaller values are in common use today and most editors can be configured. Source:
> [How many spaces for tab character(\t)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094690/how-many-spaces-for-tab-character-t)

try this and see:

```
print('123456789')
print('1\t1')
print('12\t1')
print('123\t1')
```

[image]

Comment: I understoood the rule from your examples. But I can't find out which characters before tab filled the space in my situation. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you added too much spaces in " print(day+1, "\t    ", daily, "\t\t    ", totalSalary)".
when you remove the tab spaces you will not get the "not aligned" problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`tab` is not just collection of `white spaces`

Any character before `tab` fills the space.

```py
>>> print("A\tZ")
A       Z
>>> print("AB\tZ")
AB      Z
>>> print("ABC\tZ")
ABC     Z
```

and if there are no spaces to fill tab, then it will be shifted

```
>>> print("ABCDEFGH\tZ")
ABCDEFGH        Z
```

Comment: I understoood the rule from your examples. But I can't find out which characters before tab filled the space in my situation. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic space declaration. Due to length of the digit

```
days = int(input("How many days did you work? : "))
totalSalary = 0
day_data = []
for day in range(days):
   daily = 2**day
   totalSalary += daily
   day_data.append([day+1,daily,totalSalary])
   
num_space = len(str(day_data[-1][-1]))+2
f_space_len, s_space_len = 5+num_space, 9+num_space
print(f"Day{num_space*' '}Daily Salary{num_space*' '}Total Salary")
for i in day_data:
   day, daily, totalSalary = map(str, i)
   print(day, (f_space_len-len(day)+1)*' ', daily,(s_space_len-len(daily)+1)*' ', totalSalary)
```

[image]